# Hive SQL apply query to many columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark, stored-procedures, hive

I'm very new to Hive SQL and I'm trying to apply a query to many columns. Here is the query:

```
select good_at_name, cnt
, case when cnt <= char_perc[0] then 0
    when cnt <= char_perc[1] then 1
    when cnt <= char_perc[2] then 2
    else 3
  end as char_percentile_rank
from (
 select good_at_name, cnt
     , PERCENTILE(BIGINT(cnt),array(0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)) over () as c_perc 
 from (
   select good_at_name
     , sum(cnt) as cnt             
   from good_at_name_walmart
   group by good_at_name            
 ) t1
) t2
```

Basically, this query would create a new column based on an existing column and it returns 4 groups of percentiles (%25, %50, %75 and %100) for each data value. (1st Qt, 2nd Qt, 3rd Qt, 4th Qt in statistics). Here is my input:

```
In [182]: data_set
Out[182]: 
  c_1  C_2  ...  C_1000
0  2    3          2
1  1    1          1    
2  2    2          0    
3  2    5          1     
4  4    1          3
```

So when I apply that query, I would get:

```
In [182]: result
Out[182]: 
  c_1  c_perc  C_2   ...   C_1000 
0  1    0       1             0     
1  2    1       1             1     
2  2    1       2             1     
3  2    1       3             2     
4  4    3       5             3
```

Which only returns the `c_perc` for one column like `c_1`. I'm looking for a way to apply this query to all the columns, to get this output:

```
In [182]: result
Out[182]: 
  c_1  c_perc1  C_2  c_perc2  ...  C_1000  c_perc1000
0  1      0      1      0            0         0
1  2      1      1      0            1         1
2  2      1      2      1            1         1
3  2      1      3      2            2         2
4  4      3      5      3            3         3
```

Any kinda implementation in `Scala`, `Hive` or `Spark` or so would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could approach this. At a high level, maybe something like this:

1. Load the [hive table into a DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables)
2. From the dataframe, get the columns `df.schema.fields`
3. For each field, create a new dataframe with all of the new columns (you'll have to rewrite your hive query to spark sql)

Edit: Here is a quick start I threw together. Sorry, don't have more time to flesh it out but hopefully this illustrates what I was thinking.

```
val schema = sql.types.StructType(List(
  sql.types.StructField("lions", sql.types.IntegerType, nullable = false),
  sql.types.StructField("tigers", sql.types.IntegerType, nullable = false),
  sql.types.StructField("bears", sql.types.IntegerType, nullable = false)
))
val rows = Seq(
  sql.Row(15,10,20),
  sql.Row(20,20,30),
 sql.Row(35,30,40),
  sql.Row(40,40,50),
  sql.Row(50,50,60)
)
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rows)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl")
val percentileDfs = df.schema.fields.map(field => {
  spark.sql(s"select percentile(${field.name}, array(0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)) as ${field.name}_centiles from tbl")
})
percentileDfs.foreach(_.show())
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+

|      lions_centiles|

+--------------------+

|[20.0, 35.0, 40.0...|

+--------------------+ 

+--------------------+

|     tigers_centiles|

+--------------------+

|[20.0, 30.0, 40.0...|

+--------------------+

+--------------------+

|      bears_centiles|

+--------------------+

|[30.0, 40.0, 50.0...|

+--------------------+
```

See how I'm iterating through the fields on `df.schema`? You'd probably then just collect the output from each query and then use it to generate new columns (check out spark's `withColumn`).

Comment: well thank you for your help. My problem is I don't how to start your steps!

Comment: Would you please tell me what do you mean by "create a new dataframe with all of the new columns" ?

Comment: @Dio I added a small example, hopefully this gives you a push in the right direction.